# Who is Jerry ranting about in the Bridget Everett episode of Comedians in Cars Getting Coffee?

Tags: plot-explanation, comedians-in-cars-getting-coffee

In S11E10 of [Comedians in Cars Getting Coffee](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2314952/), Bridget Everett mentions a friend of hers, but his name is censored by the show. Jerry Seinfeld immediately launches into a rant about the guy, who Jerry claims has a history of attacking Jerry out of jealousy for Jerry’s superior comedic talent. Jerry describes the person as trying to be “edgy and cool” and affecting a “stupid voice.”

**Who is the subject of this conversation? Is there any record of his feud with Seinfeld?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ComediansCarsCoffee/comments/cf67lf/whos_name_did_they_bleep_out_in_the_bridget/) users and several [articles](https://www.yourtango.com/2019326462/who-comedian-bleeped-out-jerry-seinfeld-bridget-everett-episode-comedian-in-cars-getting-coffee-bobcat-goldthwait) that also cite that Reddit post claim that it is [Bobcat Goldthwait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bobcat_Goldthwait).

Jerry and Bobcat have been feuding for a while and have both said things about each other.  At one point it the episode Jerry talks about him having to make a weird voice to be funny and Bobcat is known for his strange accent when he performs.

Comment: While I don’t subscribe to the notion that any number of concurring opinions on Reddit makes a fact out of anything (as the writer of that article seems to believe), there are some good points in that thread. Most convincing to me are the demonstrable connection between Everett and Goldthwait and the observation that Jerry’s “wild and dangerous” comment makes even more since in reference to the name “Bobcat” than to the comedian himself.

Comment: @Josh, I agree and was disappointed when the articles were just linking back to Reddit, but I agreed with the points made and it sounds correct.  I welcome another answer with an original source tho, but I fear it will just be more speculation.